# Sorting time in txt file written with Filewriter

Tags: java, sorting, filewriter, bufferedwriter

**My problem is**. I am writing a program to make reservations. For this I use Filewriter and Buffered write to write it to a txt file. The input is trough simpleInoutDialog and It gives a string with the template hh:mm:ss.

This I write to the txt file along with a name
example:

```
08:00:00
Tom Hanks
06:20:00
Henry Bigs
```

What I'm trying to do is to sort the date so I can read it easily?
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j) or [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) or [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) and make pattern:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Framework will sort messages for you.

Comment: Where does this code needs to be in my java code  so it works?

Comment: Add logback.xml to your project to source - I included the content above, see [Logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html) for details. Add [logback-classic](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.0.0), [logback-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.0.0) and [slf4j-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4) to your classpath. And see [slf4j manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). I prefer maven project, because then all depedencies are fetched for me.